# Inserting rows above a specified rows

Tags: vba, insert, rows

I am wondering how to insert 3 extra rows above a specified row that has "order type" (as specified below).

This row occurs multiple times in the sheet. The below code works, except it inserts the rows below the specified row. Thanks

```
Sub try()
    Dim c As Range

    For Each c In Range("A1:A100")
        If c.Value Like "*Order Type*" Then
            c.Offset(3, 0).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4):

If your problem is to add 3 extra rows above searched criteria, solving your problem should be easy:

In you code line:

```
c.Offset(3, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

Your line says when order type is found he should go 3 rows below and insert extra row.

Should go like this:

```
c.EntireRow.Resize(3).Insert
```

My line says, when order type is found, add 3 extra rows above it.

Hope this is what you looking for.

Edited:

I've searched Internet and found something similar to your problem and changed it according to you needs. Hope this will work for you. 
Little explanation how it works: it searches all the way through A column and if "*Order Type*" was found it adds 3 rows above it. When macro goes to blank cell it stops. Try it and tell me if it works good for you.

```
Sub AddRows()

Dim lastValue As String, i As Long, r As Long
Do
    r = r + 1
    If r > 1 And Cells(r, 1).Value Like "*Order Type*" Then
        If Cells(r, 1).Value = "" Then Exit Do
        For i = 1 To 3
            Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlUp
        Next
        r = r + 3

        Else
            If IsEmpty(Cells(r, 1)) = True Then
            Exit Do

            Else

            End If

    End If
    lastValue = Cells(r, 1).Value
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks a lot that works, but how would I code to loop it so it doesnt keep re searching the entire sheet. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you found it helpful - mark it as answered, so ppl can use this later on ;) If talking about loop code that was provided by Ripster, do - loop method has it's limits, you can read something about it here: http://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/loops.php

Comment: Sorry again, I have been trying all these different loops and it just keeps searching the whole sheet and I am seriously confused.  Sorry for all the small questions it is just giving me huge amounts of trouble. Thanks!

Comment: oh... I see the problem, unofortunately no time now to fix this. I'll try to think about it.

Comment: Try updated code. It's very different but should work for you. Let me know if it's good.

Answer (score 1):

This should go up three rows instead of down three:

```
c.Offset(-3, 0).EntireRow.Insert
```

Use caution with this because if there are not three rows above the current row it will throw an error. A safer way to do this is by inserting from the current row + 2 more and shifting everything down.

```
Rows(c.Row & ":" & c.Row + 2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

**Edit:** The reason it runs until excel freezes is due to the way your loop is constructed. The first time it finds a match it inserts rows and then continues on finds the same match again causing it to get stuck in an infinite loop.

You can try this and see if it does what you want, it worked for me.

```
Sub try()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range

    Do While i < ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
        i = i + 1
        Set c = Cells(i, 1)

        If c.Value Like "*Order Type*" Then
            Rows(c.Row & ":" & c.Row + 2).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
            i = i + 3
        End If
        Debug.Print i
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I enter the first one into the code it gives me this message

Comment: that says there is an object error, also the second one just runs the macro and then my excel says not responding, not sure of the problem there, let me know if you have suggestions, thanks!

Comment: It still gave me the same error, is there anything else I can try? Thanks